# Change color of Rectangle2D object by double clicking on it

Tags: java, swing, awt

I need to change the mouseClicked function so it will change Rectangle2D color to red

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event) {
            current = find(event.getPoint());
            if (current != null && event.getClickCount() >= 2) {
                remove(current);
                
            }
        }

public Rectangle2D find(Point2D p) {
        for(Rectangle2D r : squares)
            if(r.contains(p))
                return r;
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: 1) Create a custom object with two properties: Rectangle and Color 2) Create an ArrayList that contains instances of these objects. 3) in the paintComponent() method you iterate through this list to paint each rectangle. 4) in your mouseClicked event you search this ArrayLIst to find the Rectangle that was clicked and change the color and then repaint the component. See the `DrawOnComponent` example from [Custom Painting Approaches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/) for a working example to get you started. You just need to add the mouseClicked logic.

Comment: Help us to help you. You can improve this question by editing it to show more code, preferably a [complete but minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what you have so far.

Comment: Hi,  user20377701, and welcome to Stack Overflow. To better understand Stack Overflow and how to use it, here are some resources: [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Rectangle2D doesn't have color properties it depends on the way you paint it.